# Calculate array length (sizeof str / sizeof (char)) won't work

Tags: c, arrays, string, sizeof

The function `getStringEnd()` doesn't work correctly but I don't know why. The function does not return the correct value of the string end. I already found out that the variable `max` is not calculated right.

But
`int max = sizeof str / sizeof (char);`
should work, shouldn't it?

Do you have any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_FIGURES 30  

int getStringEnd(const char * str);

int getStringEnd(const char * str)
{
    int max = sizeof str / sizeof (char);

    int counter = 0;
    while (counter <= max -1)
    {
        if ((str[counter] == '\0') || (str[counter] == '\n')) return counter;
        counter += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char figures[MAX_FIGURES];
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_FIGURES - 1; i++) figures[i] = '\0';

    fgets(figures, MAX_FIGURES, stdin);

    int stringEnd = getStringEnd(&figures);
}
```

Comment: Please find the answer to this question in any C FAQ, such as [this](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html).

Answer (score 6):

In `getStringEnd()` function, `str` is a `const char *`, nothing else. `sizeof` operator gives back the size of the datatype, not the amount of memory *pointed  by* the variable.

You need to use [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) to get the length of the *string*. You need to write something like

```
int max = strlen(str); // sizeof(char) == 1, fixed, can be ommitted
```

<sup>Note: FWIW, Remember, `strlen()` does not take into account the terminating null.</sup>

Comment: That fixes the problem. I just wonder why my code do not work, I have a book of C programming and the author used the code `sizeof array / array[0]` to get the elements of a array. I not understand what the real problem of my program is.

Comment: @Domi it is possible when `array` if of type `<type>[n]`. In case of a pointer, sizeof won't work as you might expect.